# jQuery Selector to retrieve contents after certain HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I want to retrieve all the html elements after `font:first` element inside `p` in the below code.

```
<p class="rrp">
    <font color="#ff6600">
        <strong>
            Save 20% on in-house Frames and Sunglasses
            <br>
            Save 10% on Contact Lens and Branded Frames
            <br>
            Ask at the counter for more details
        </strong>
    </font>
    <br>
    GKB Opticals, Shop No. EB-GF-10, Block East, Ground Floor, Town Centre - Amanora Mall, Amanora Park Township, Village Sadesatranali (17-1/2 Nali), Hadapsar, Taluka Haveli,
    <br>Pune - 411 028.
    <br>
    <font color="#339900">Validity:</font>
     31st March 2013
</p>​
```

So, the result would be

```
<br>
GKB Opticals, Shop No. EB-GF-10, Block East, Ground Floor, Town Centre - Amanora Mall, Amanora Park Township, Village Sadesatranali (17-1/2 Nali), Hadapsar, Taluka Haveli,
<br>Pune - 411 028.
<br>
<font color="#339900">Validity:</font>
 31st March 2013
```

I should give you some code I've done, but I have no idea how to fetch the elements after certain element.

Could anyone guide me?
thanks!

Comment: What you show isn't only elements but also text nodes. What do you want to do with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nextAll` method which selects all following siblings of the element.

```
$('.rrp font:first').nextAll()
```

If you want to exclude the first font element, you can use `filter` method.

```
var $ff = $('.rrp font:first')
$('.rrp').contents().filter(function(){
    return !$(this).is($ff)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7VSY/

Comment: It only selects the nextAll `font` element. I need to select all the elements after certain element.

Comment: What do you mean by all elements, the textnodes aren't really elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since pretty much all css selectors are supported by jQuery, you can probably just use the after-sibling selector, `~`, followed by the all selector, `*`.

```
$('.rrp font:first ~ *')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.rrp font:first').nextAll()`
but it will return all `<br>` and `<font color="#339900">Validity:</font>` only, as other content will not get selected as they are part of `<p>`
you should move all text inside a element

Modified html:

```
    <p class="rrp">
        <font color="#ff6600">
            <strong>
                Save 20% on in-house Frames and Sunglasses
                <br>
                Save 10% on Contact Lens and Branded Frames
                <br>
                Ask at the counter for more details
            </strong>
        </font>
        <br>
        <div>GKB Opticals, Shop No. EB-GF-10, Block East, Ground Floor, Town Centre - Amanora Mall, Amanora Park Township, Village Sadesatranali (17-1/2 Nali), Hadapsar, Taluka Haveli,
        <br>Pune - 411 028.
        <br>
 </div>
        <font color="#339900">Validity:</font>
         <div>31st March 2013</div>
    </p>​
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to get a copy of your `.rrp` content without the first font element and everything before, you can do this :

```
var $rrp = $('.rrp').clone();
$rrp.find(':lt('+($rrp.find('font:first').index()+1)+')').remove();
var $rrpContent = $rrp.html();
```

`$rrp` in this case contains also the text nodes.

But the code you need really depends on your use case. Is that for cleaning ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use: `$('.rrp font:first').nextAll()`. But as @Shsul said, only elements surrounded with a tag will get selected, not the text only.